# Create new column based of two columns

Tags: dataframe, loops, if-statement, lambda, calculated-columns

I have two columns in a dataframe. I want to create third column such that if first column > second column than 1 ow 0. As below

Df

Value1  value 2.  Newcolumn

100. ```
       101.      0
     ```
101. ```
         97.      1
     ```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing two columns in a Pandas DataFrame and write the results of the comparison to a third column. It can do easily by these syntaxes

```
conditions=[(condition1),(condition2)]
choices=["choice1","choice2"]

df["new_column_name"]=np.select(conditions, choices, default)
```

1. **conditions** are the conditions to check for between the two columns
2. **choices** are the results to return based on the conditions
3. **np.select** is used to return the results to the new column

The dataframe is:

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

```
#create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value1': [100,101],
                   'value 2': [101,97]})


#define conditions
conditions = [df['Value1'] < df['value 2'], 
              df['Value1'] > df['value 2']]

#define choices
choices = ['0', '1']

#create new column in DataFrame that displays results of comparisons
df['Newcolumn'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='Tie')
```

Final dataframe

```
print(df)
```

Output:

```
Value1  value 2 Newcolumn
0     100      101         0
1     101       97         1
```